# create pdf with FUTURA font in java

Tags: java, itext

Here I am creating the pdf with FUTURA font but my BaseFont.createFont method is giving error. Currently, PDF is being created successfully with Halvetica font but I want that to be created with FUTURA font.

Here I am using itextpdf5.5.13.jar for this activity
I have tried importing tiff file using

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("futura",BaseFont.TIMES_ITALIC, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, bytesArray, null);
```

But it is giving error

```
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Font 'futura' with 'Identity-H' is not recognized.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:716)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:625)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:568)
```

This is the code I am using to write in the PDF.

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();        
File file = new File(p.getProperty("FONTFILE"));
byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; 
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("futura",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, bytesArray, null);
cb.saveState();
cb.beginText();
cb.moveText(x, y);
cb.setFontAndSize(bf, size);
cb.showText(text);
cb.endText();
cb.restoreState();
```

Expected result should be "PDF should create using Futura font"
But it is throwing exception.

Comment: As what type of font is futura encoded in the `bytesArray`? If a TrueType font, try `"futura.ttf"`, if an OpenType font, try `"futura.otf"` etc

Comment: Futura is window font also I have ttf file of this font. Can you suggest how to use this font in Basefont class.

Comment: See above, *try "futura.ttf"* instead of "futura".

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I passed ttf file with entire path and font applied.

Comment: Ok, I'll make that an actual answer you can accept.

Comment: You may want to accept my answer by clicking the tick at its upper left, right underneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

`BaseFont.createFont` uses the first parameter to determine the type of font to instantiate.

- If it is a standard 14 font name or a CJK font name (from the Adobe CJK font pack, I assume), the font is initialized from the known characteristics thereof without embedding.
- If it is ending with ".afm" or ".pfm", the font is initialized as type 1 font.
- If it is ending with ".ttf" or ".otf", or contains ".ttc,", the font is initialized as a true type font.
- Otherwise (depending on the `boolean noThrow` parameter) `null` is returned or an `Exception` is thrown.

In the case at hand a true type font shall be loaded. Thus, in

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("futura",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, bytesArray, null);
```

replace "futura" by "futura.ttf". Or even, as you eventually did, use the complete path and file name of the font file.